# Nested Recyclerview

Tags: nested, android-recyclerview

How to implement Nested recyclerview in android. I have to implement one recyclerview containing two buttons and inside that recyclerview again in second recyclerview two images have to be there how to implement this can anyone suggest me i am new to android

Comment: try to use the [RendererRecyclerViewAdapter](https://github.com/vivchar/RendererRecyclerViewAdapter)

Answer (score 2):

You cannot place a `RecyclerView` inside another `RecyclerView` within a layout xml file. But you can programatically attach a `RecyclerView` into another one. For example by attaching Layouts programatically. Then you would have two scrollable `RecyclerView`s. This may sometimes be a thing you don't want to have. For example because of `CollapsingToolbarLayout`s. Then you can deactivate nested scrolling of the inner `RecyclerView` by

```
mRecyclerView.setNestedScrollingEnabled(false);
```

But if you disable scrolling you will lose the performance advantage of the `RecyclerView` because the inner one does not recycle anymore if it is not scrollable. But maybe you just need something like this [SectionedRecyclerViewAdapter](https://github.com/luizgrp/SectionedRecyclerViewAdapter).

Answer (score 0):

Yes we can implement Nested RecyclerView in Android Studio

Just make a Child Adapter and its xml layout and set that adapter inside the Parent Adapter. You can refer to our blog if your have any doubt.

[How to Implement Nested RecyclerView in Android](https://www.gradlebuilders.ml/2021/02/how-to-make-play-store-like-layout-in.html)